# How to escape command line arguments on PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

It appears that I can escape command line arguments using single or double quotes:

```
PS C:\> echo Hello World
Hello
World
PS C:\> echo 'Hello World'
Hello World
PS C:\> echo "Hello World"
Hello World
```

But there's still something I can't figure out, which is when you wish to run an executable from a directory that contains a space in it:

```
PS C:\> c:\program files\test.exe
The term 'c:\program' is not recognized as a cmdlet, function, operable program, or script file. Verify the term and try again.
At line:1 char:11
+ c:\program  <<<< files\test.exe
PS C:\> 'c:\program files\test.exe'
c:\program files\test.exe
PS C:\> "c:\program files\test.exe"
c:\program files\test.exe
PS C:\>
```

How do I get PowerShell to run the executable above?

Comment: https://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2007/11/24/effective-powershell-item-10-understanding-powershell-parsing-modes/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this:

```
. "c:\program files\test.exe"
```

Actually an even better solution would be:

```
Invoke-Item "c:\program files\test.exe"
```

or using the alias:

```
ii "c:\program files\test.exe"
```

Using Invoke-Item means that the proper Windows file handler would be used. So for an EXE file it would run it. For a .doc file for instance, it would open it in Microsoft Word.

Here is one of the handiest PowerShell command lines around. Give it a try:

```
ii .
```

Comment: [Invoke-Item is evil](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful/).

Comment: Invoke-Expression certainly has security concerns associated with it's use but I'm not aware of issues with Invoke-Item. Could you elaborate?

Comment: You probably want to use `&` instead of `.` if you're trying to call an executable.  The `.` call operator is really intended for including other PowerShell scripts in the current context.  See [`Get-Help about_Operators`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-6).

Answer (score 20):

Try putting an ampersand before the command. For example

```
& 'C:\Program Files\winscp\winscp.exe'
```

Comment: This is the more correct answer as it simply tells the parser to interpret the next token in command mode, though it looks like a string.